# What picture book featured warring factions of mole-like creatures?

Tags: story-identification

I recall a colorful children's fantasy picture book with the following details:

- It featured a world inhabited by strange creatures, perhaps moles or another mammal, like a bear, or perhaps even wombat. They dressed like humans. Many had shaven heads or short hair.
- There were two factions, locked in a cold war of sorts.
- They had setup various contraptions to spy on each other, such as hidden phone booths cut into a tree, tunnels, etc.
- One group's uniforms were inspired by Prussian army symbolism, wearing Pickelhaube helmets.

Can anyone identify this book?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe this is the Trumpets series, by artist Peter Cross and writer Peter Dallas-Smith. The Trumpets are "peaceful, gentle creatures, but are threatened by Grumpets – mean, warlike bullies, out to make trouble." Both sides look like tiny anthropomorphic hippos. You can see sample pictures on Cross's website [here](https://petercrossart.com/books/trumpets/trouble-for-trumpets); note the lookout within the hollow tree in the Marchwood picture.